# How to group lines of text using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace, carriage-return

I find Notepad++ regex to be very different from regex in Microsoft Word. I was wondering how I can group several lines of text using Notepad++. I have a text file with 100+ URLs. They are written one URL address per line. I would like to group all of them by tens by removing the carriage returns from every first to 9th line, but retaining the carriage return on every 10th line and adding another carriage return thereafter. For example:

I want this:

```
http://website1.com
http://website2.com
http://website3.com
http://website4.com
http://website5.com
http://website6.com
http://website7.com
http://website8.com
http://website9.com
http://website10.com
http://website11.com
http://website12.com
http://website13.com
http://website14.com
http://website15.com
http://website16.com
http://website17.com
http://website18.com
http://website19.com
http://website20.com
http://website21.com
http://website22.com
http://website23.com
http://website24.com
http://website25.com
http://website26.com
http://website27.com
http://website28.com
http://website29.com
http://website30.com
```

to look like:

```
http://website1.comhttp://website2.comhttp://website3.comhttp://website4.comhttp://website5.comhttp://website6.comhttp://website7.comhttp://website8.comhttp://website9.comhttp://website10.com

http://website11.comhttp://website12.comhttp://website13.comhttp://website14.comhttp://website15.comhttp://website16.comhttp://website17.comhttp://website18.comhttp://website19.comhttp://website20.com

http://website21.comhttp://website22.comhttp://website23.comhttp://website24.comhttp://website25.comhttp://website26.comhttp://website27.comhttp://website28.comhttp://website29.comhttp://website30.com
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, I think this is not possible, because there are no things like {a,b} and so on in Notepad++. It's easier to write a tool in Java, for example.

Comment: @StKiller Thanks for your reply. I thought this was possible because I read so many things about how powerful Notepad++ is when it comes to regular expressions. :( About Java, I'm afraid I have no knowledge of it. If it's not too much to ask of me, could you write the code for the this Java tool you are saying?

Comment: @techdaemon: Regex support is one of the *weakest*  spots of Notepad++. Sadly enough.

Comment: @techdaemon: You have read a lot of lies.

Comment: Notepad++ regex search is _lame_. It can't find: `'\n'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have found a way:

There is a such possibility, but only with 6 entries in a row (longest regex is not parsed by the Notepad++).

1)So, open the file and remove from it all newlines characters, so the text will be a long-long line.

2)Open replace dialog, insert in the "Find what" field the next :

`(http://[^\:]*\.comhttp://[^\:]*\.comhttp://[^\:]*\.comhttp://[^\:]*\.comhttp://[^\:]*\.comhttp://[^\:]*\.com)`

and in the "Replace With" the next:

```
\1\r\n
```

Put the cursor at the first position in the text and press "Replace all"

So, the regex contains this `(http://[^\:]*\.com){6}` (the regex is repeated 6 times). If you work with Unix and you need unix-type new line style, replace this : `\1\r\n` with this `\1\n`

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful somehow. I'm just going to perform the find-and-replace with the regex you provided twice, one with two entries in a row and another with five so that it totals ten and my problem is solved. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be replacing with `\r\n` instead of `\n\r` for Windows line endings.